# How can I use the demonic corpses to create my army?

Tags: biology, magic

My name is Grimdarkus Prime, and I am a madman. I have dreams of world conquest and plan to build an army made up of demonic soldiers that are stronger and faster than regular humans. To do this, I have invented what are known as behelits, vast artificial wombs made up of the corpses of demons stitched together. These behelits are infused with demonic energy from the warp, a reflection of humanity's darkest fears and desires. This is a realm where emotions and nightmares are sentient, and its energies corrupt the human form. I will use this to create the perfect blend of man and demon, and make a vast army subject to my will.

I plan to use the prisoners and populations taken during conquest to make this army. Tens of thousands of people have been enslaved and given the honor of being candidates for this process. Adult humans have fully grown into their bodies and are no longer changing on a genetic level. Most devolve into chaos spawn, which are monstrosities with horrible mutations and are uncontrollable. This makes them little better than canon fodder, and they die in a number of weeks if nothing else kills them. Children seem like a better candidate, since they are blank slates and are still growing. However, they are too weak to survive the infusion of demon energy, and either drown during the process or are physically destroyed by the process.

How can I solve this conundrum and increase the success rate of my process in order to build this army?

Comment: Is using animals a viable solution?

Comment: uhh, are you in a universe where people all live on one world and fight each other with oversized war hammers, or in a universe where people live on many worlds and fight each other with guns and oversized war hammers?

Comment: @Deolater regardless, this sounds like heresy

Comment: Demons that have corporeal and leave corpses when they die? Then are they really 'demons' at all?

Comment: Sounds like someone has been watching/reading *Berserk*.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Improve your terrible behelit!**

The problem is your behelit is a piece of junk and ruins most candidates.  It needs to be improved.  Ideas:

1. **Corpse wombs bad**.  Corpse wombs have a bad track record of producing offspring, and your giant magic womb is made of corpses.  If you really need that thing, I recommend using live demons.
2. **Different energy source**.  Your warp energy is corruptive to the human form.   It says that on the sign.  And you wonder why your humans get corrupted?  Get energy from someplace where something other than darkest fears and desires are made sentient.  Maybe someplace where half baked schemes are made sentient, or cheesy love songs are made sentient.  That will be less corruptive.  If you want a little bit of corruptive to keep things spooky that is cool.  Sort of like crackers have palm oil and coconut oil *and* peanut oil in them.  That makes them good, I think.
3. **Use volunteers and keep them human**.  I am worried that if you take unwilling slaves and make them perfectly blended demonic soldiers, they be will pissed off demon soldiers with horns and ichor and stuff.  Probably they will team up and come for you.   Becoming a demon does not make you all tractable.  I bet if you did not kill those regular demons so you could build stuff with their corpses, that bunch could be your demon soldiers.  The humans could stay humans and they might be more enthusiastic that way.  Promise them governorships and slave wives / slave husbands from your new conquered territories, like ISIS does.  The demons could lead them if those two groups get along.  You could give the humans demon costumes if you want.  I would.
4. **Get less mad**.  Dude (if I may call you dude): you have conquered and enslaved tens of thousands of people with whatever army you have now.  And this without the corpse womb.  You are doing something right!  Don't change it up with this warp energy.  Probably this is about displaced anger with your ex.  Find someone you can talk to and work through these issues; maybe some medicine, maybe less hobnobbing with sentient nightmares and wet dreams.  In any case let your generals do what they clearly do well.

Comment: I damn near spat out my coffee. +1

Answer (score 13):

Use teenagers, and hit them hard as soon as they start puberty.

They're strong enough to survive the mutations and their mind are already in a chaos state that you can use in your advantage. Just focus their minds on horrible and magnificent things from the warp and they'll respond to that as any teenager would, adapting.

Let their rage and conflicting desires overwhelm those feelings they feed upon and rise as an individual rather than a mindless beast. Have you ever seen love so pure as a young love? Or else, have you ever been the target of a teenage rage or hatred? They feel more, they experience more, so everything you feed them they absorb like a demoniac sponge and are shaped by it.

Answer (score 2):

**Take a More Gradual Approach**

Why would they need to be fully turned into demons all at once. Try slowing down the transformation with tricks such as multiple times in either less potent behelits, or short periods in the standard behelit. If that isn't possible, then try exposing your prisoners to demonic energies  before putting them in the behelits. Feeding them small amounts of demonic flesh, or having them sleep in cells filled with demonic energy. The goal is to reduce how far the transformation needs to go all at once so as to lessen the stress.

Answer (score 1):

**Farm and Use Pregnant Women**

- The fetuses wont drown because they are still in the womb and the mother can act as a buffer to ease the transformation (a steadier more gradual transformation).
- The fetus is more undeveloped allowing for the greatest possible assimilation with the demonic energy.
- And you get a two-fer. A well blended man demon as well as a demon spawn mother.
- You can also farm out your humans to make an assembly line as all you need is a steady stream of pregnant women. If you are lucky you might be able to selectively breed the women to support multiple pregnancies and transformations allowing for even higher production rate.
- Maybe you can stud out your hybrids to produce even more powerful and successful hybrids.
- use women between the ages 14 and 20 as they generally survive and rebound from the birthing process more successfully. Women who survive the first birthing should be returned to the farms to spread their successful breeding genes.
- Perhaps holier women, women whom are more aligned with light energies, will make better breeders as their faith will prevent them from being transformed thus allowing them to be reused. It could also be that their energy dilutes the demonic energy feeding into the baby reducing the shock and making the process more gradual. (this by the way is an epic way for a dark army to pervert a holy force and engage in the practice of supporting their mortal enemies - imagine the irony of a dark army actually building holy temples).

Ahhh the sweet depravity